# Separating and Managing Unity projects on GitHub

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, version-control, 3d, repository

I have a Unity project on GitHub currently, but the repository has become too large with all the 3D files and videos. I would like to separate the GitHub repository into multiple repositories, but I don't how I should go about doing that. I would like to know if there is a general rule of thumb or proper way of doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Background: I'm running Github Enterprise on a private server. The repository is becoming bigger and bigger and as a result, git operations (cloning etc) is using up alot of the resources. I would like to separating the repository into 2 or more repositories to prevent overusing resources.

Comment: Just to verify I understand you correctly. You have one project which you would like to separate into 2 or more Github repositories so you more easily have an overview of each?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Doh09. Sorry for not being clear, I'm running Github Enterprise on a private server. The repository is becoming bigger and bigger and as a result, git operations (cloning etc) is using up alot of the resources. Separating it into 2 or more repositories should remedy the resource issue. My question is, how should I organize them accordingly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since scripts, scenes, prefabs and other light weight files are also likely to be changed the most often, it would seem fitting to make one repository for these and then another repository for more heavy files such as textures, models and audio files.

Exactly how to split it up would depend on what files of yours take up the most space.

So, make a light weight repository which is the one you update the most frequently. Then split the remaining heavier files into repositories in a way that makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. So if I split the project into 2 repositories, I would have to set .gitignore for each repository right? Could you name some pros and cons of managing it this way? thanks

Comment: Well as for pros, the packages are easier update for other people if they for example only need to update the light package and are on slow internet. Same goes for you if you switch between computers. Con is that you manage multiple github repos instead of just one. As for whether or not you need a .gitignore in each folder, I do believe you need that, but better google it just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion